# RPi 4 won't connect to wifi extender

Tags: wifi, connection

I have a RPi 4 which i am wanting to setup wirelessly - this works fine on my home WiFi. But because I am very far away from my router (other side of house) it is incredibly slow. I do have a WiFi extender about 3m away but it will not connect to it. I have the correct password and SSID, the extender is 5GHz, the key_mgmt is correct I believe (the extender says it is WPA3 - unsure if I should be using the security key of the router? I have tried both anyways.) The pi doesn't show up on WiFi scanners at all when using the extender, and can't be pinged.

How can I fix this? I currently don't have a micro-hdmi cable and would like to avoid getting one but am thinking I will have to - anything I can do?

Comment: `The pi doesn't show up on WiFi scanners at all` it's a client, it won't show up on any scans, does the extender show up on the pi? Do other devices use the extender successfully?

Comment: Yes the extender shows up on the pi and yes the extender works with other things - I’ve had it for about a year. I am trying to set it up to be headless (I think) so it can be controlled and used by another computer

Comment: Not sure if pi does WPA3 - can the extender do WPA2 and WPA3?